# Why did Spring Boot lose its Handler Mapping?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, connection

So, earlier today I was doing a performance test for database connection pool changes. We used JMeter to do the performance test, about 3 requests were made every 2 seconds. Each request had the exact same POST request for GraphQL, with no changes in header, body, or path. Note, the request was using graphql doing a query, it did not change anything.

But after the 50th request, all the requests got failure responses. I noticed in the logs, we started to get `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` for `Did not find handler method for [/path/to/api]`, the url path that was used this entire time. The failures that were reported in JMeter were ether Connection reset or Connection aborted.

I had once done the same performance test yesterday, and this did not occur. I ran it again today, but I previously looked at the wrong metric during the last time.
When the failure occurred, it also failed with other rest calls, and failed on our simple health check endpoint.

Update: A few minutes later, the API started working again. No idea why.

Comment: Do specify the host environment / configuration for the app being stress tested. Also do share the CPU / memory utilization while the said issue occurred (if it is not available do capture it for latest run)

Comment: Try enabling the TRACE level logs -       logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE

Comment: I would try it, but I have yet to replicate the failure.

Comment: Most probably it could be a memory problem. Check your ram usage  while you're doing a performance test

Comment: Did you used JMeter JDBC connection also? maybe you left previous JMeter execution unclosed?

Answer (score 0):

`RequestMappingHandlerMapping` for `Did not find handler method for [/path/to/api]`,

This behavior is normal when a resource/path `[/path/to/api]` is not found during a lapse of time when it is calling. I used to use `JMeter` to do performance tests but I left to use because I had different metrics as you have. Why? so far I researched about it, it is due to `JMeter` runs a main thread because is developed by Java. Then I looked an alternative tool in order to have measures of performance tests consistently. I used [Gatling](https://gatling.io/) tool and I get measures of performance tests consistently until now.